# Any visual studio 2010 extension for auto concatenation on new line?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, string-concatenation

i have this question about visual studio 2010... in mono develop, when i have a string like this:

```
string s = "hello, how are you";
```

and if i press enter key on the beginning of the "how...", the code changes automatically to this:

```
string s = "hello, " + 
"how are you?";
```

Is some extension in visual studio 2010 for this auto concatenation on a new string line?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry, i am quite new in stackoverflow and i would like to know what is this 10%.. :)

Comment: It means you've asked 14 questions, had answers provided for 10 of them, and only accepted one of those answers. Click the tick if the answer helps you.

Comment: Presumably the compiler is smart enough to optimise all these concatenated strings into one literal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you expecting any escape sequences in your string? If not, you can just use a [Verbatim String Literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

```
string s = @"Hello,
how are you?";
```

Then you have no need for a VS extension.

Obviously, this will only work if you are not concerned with the additional whitespace which will get added. If you need to just split the lines in code, but have them on one line in the resulting application, this will not work.

Comment: I know that, but i think more in a VS extension that does automatically for me. Thanks for the answer :)